# Law of iterated expectation for the square of a conditional expectation

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, expected-value, conditional-expectation

We know from the law of iterated expectations that $$E[E[X|Y]] = E[X]$$
However, does the same hold true for the square of a conditional expectation? I.e. is the following expression true,
$$E[E[X|Y]^2] = E[X]^2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the proposed relation does not hold which is clear from the special
case when $X$ and $Y$ are identical, the l.h.s. being then $E(X^2)$.

With $\text{Var}[X \vert Y] := E[X^2 \vert Y ] - 
 E[X  \vert  Y ]^2$
one can use the following relation
$$
  \text{Var}(X) = E\{ \text{Var}[X \vert Y] \} +
    \text{Var}\{E[X \vert  Y]\}
$$
which is named *law of the total variance*. By rearranging we find
$$
    E\{E[X \vert  Y]^2\} = E(X)^2 +
    \text{Var}\{E[X \vert Y]\}.
$$

Comment: I'm having a little trouble deriving the formula for $Var[X|Y] = E[X^2|Y] - E[X|Y]^2$. Particularly, when expanding the squared expression $E[(Y-E(Y|X))^2|X]$, it is required to simplify the term $E[E[Y|X]^2|X]$ to $E[Y|X]^2$. What is the justification for $E[Y|X]^2$ being constant in $X$?

Comment: Well $E[Y \vert X]^2$ is a function of $X$ so conditioning on $X$ does not change it. It is often useful to regard the conditional expectation as a projection.